# Cannot Hear Headphones (Stereo + Microphone in; Plugged in Using Jack)

Tags: 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, audio-jack

I have been trying to use a fresh dual boot install of Ubuntu, and I can hear sound out of speakers plugged into my monitor, but not from my headset (plugged in with a jack). This is not a problem with the other OS I am dual booting into.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

According to pavucontrol, whenever an application tries to play sound out of my headphones, it seems to pick up input on the headset's microphone... perhaps a confusion of audio source / sinks?

Output of `pacmd dump | xclip -o -selection clipboard`

```
### Configuration dump generated at Sat Jun 10 18:08:41 2023

load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-connect
load-module module-udev-detect
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="1" name="usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-bluez5-discover
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-default-device-restore
load-module module-always-sink
load-module module-intended-roles
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
load-module module-systemd-login
load-module module-position-event-sounds
load-module module-role-cork
load-module module-snap-policy
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="0" name="pci-0000_2d_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_2d_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-cli-protocol-unix

set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2 0x10000
set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2 no
suspend-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2 no
set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo 0x9469
set-sink-mute alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo no
suspend-sink alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo no

set-source-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor no
suspend-source alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor no
set-source-volume alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo.monitor no
suspend-source alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo.monitor no
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo 0xa186
set-source-mute alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo no
suspend-source alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo no

set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_2d_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo-extra2

set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo

### EOF
```

Output of `lspci | egrep -i "audio|usb" | xclip -selection clipboard`

```
2a:00.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
2a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
2d:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
2f:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
2f:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```